# How do you add the NID as a view filter criteria and not contextual filter?

Tags: views, entities

I'm using an Entity Reference field, displayed as a View, to select an "Work Entry" node type. The Work Entry nodes are selected when creating/editing an "Invoice" content type. So the user will be able to select or deselect Work Entries as needed.

My problem is when using Contextual Filters to pass the NID (Content ID from URL) it removes my other filter which is set to NID = Empty. I would like to display all Work Entries selected by current node or ones that aren't connected to any node. Hopefully this makes sense.

Any suggestions, thoughts, etc.? Drupal has so many ways to do the same thing, I may be approaching this from the wrong direction.

[image: Entries View]