# How to add a path filter to views 3 in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

This question is similar/related to [How do you add the NID as a view filter criteria and not contextual filter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110311/how-do-you-add-the-nid-as-a-view-filter-criteria-and-not-contextual-filter)

Is it possible to add a filter criterion to a view so that it filters the aliased path for a node?
*Content:Path* is available as a display field but not as a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Views URL alias](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_url_alias) module.

> **The 'Views URL alias' module allows Views to be filtered by path aliases**.
>
> This module is useful if your website uses heirachical paths. It allows you to filter and sort a view by URL aliases. When combined with the [Views bulk operation (VBO)](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module you can apply operations to a specific section of your website based on a URL alias.

Note that Currently, only node aliases are supported.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaMohan that was truly useful! That was exactly what I wanted to use it for

Comment: @YannisP. Glad to hear that :)